# ScriptedImporterEditor don't work Unity tools

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, assets

I'm Unity **tools** developper and i want to create an **event** when the user **import** a .FBX file

My code :

```
using System.IO;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEditor.Experimental.AssetImporters;
using UnityEngine;

[CustomEditor(typeof(EmptinessImporter))]
[CanEditMultipleObjects]
public class EmptinessImporterEditor : ScriptedImporterEditor
{
    //Let the parent class know that the Apply/Revert mechanism is skipped.
    protected override bool needsApplyRevert => false;

    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        // Draw some information
        EditorGUILayout.HelpBox("Because this Importer doesn't have any settings, the Apply/Revert buttons are hidden.", MessageType.None);
    }
}

[ScriptedImporter(0, ".fbx")]
public class EmptinessImporter : ScriptedImporter
{
    public override void OnImportAsset(AssetImportContext ctx)
    {
        Debug.Log(ctx.assetPath);
    }
}
```

Error :

> Scripted importers EmptinessImporter and EmptinessImporter are targeting the fbx extension, rejecting both.
> UnityEditor.Experimental.AssetImporters.ScriptedImporter:RegisterScriptedImporters()

But that doesn't work, I'm working on Unity 2019.4.9f1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you have two concurrent implementations with the same name and both targeting `fbx`.

However, if you anynway do not really want to specifically **handle** the import but rather just **react** with an event once a specific import has happened you might rather want to implement an [`AssetPostprocessor`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AssetPostprocessor.html) like maybe e.g.

```
#if UNITY_EDITOR
using System;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;

public class FbxPostProcessor : AssetPostprocessor
{
    public static event Action<string, GameObject> OnFBXImported; 
    
    private void OnPostprocessModel(GameObject gameObject)
    {
        if (assetPath.EndsWith(".fbx", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
        {
            Debug.Log($"An FBX file \"{assetPath}\" has been imported!");
                
            OnFBXImported?.Invoke(assetPath, gameObject);
        }
    }
}
#endif
```

so another editor script could simply listen to

```
FbxPostProcessor.OnFBXImported += SomeCallback;
```

---

[image]